# matplotlib - creating bars on x axis per group on y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data frame:

```
  data = pd.DataFrame(data={'group': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 'start': [2, 5, 9], 'end': [9, 8, 6]})
```

I would love to create the following graph, I've searched everywhere
and couldn't find an answer:

graph

[image]

I have looked everywhere, on matplotlib website, on pandas,
i couldn't find a simple way to perform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use matplotlib [`barh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh.html) to draw horizontal bars.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'group': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                              'start': [2, 5, 6], 'end': [9, 8, 9]})

plt.barh(data["group"], data["end"]-data["start"], 0.4, data["start"], 
         color="None", edgecolor=["blue", "red", "green"])
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: first of all , thanks to you both!
how would you do it, if the dataframe instead of number,
had time? im trying to do it with x axis as hours instead of just random numbers

Comment: It'll sure depend on the format in which the time is stored inside the DataFrame. But the basic approach shown here should work the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Rectangle` Class from `matplotlib.patches`
[see here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html)

This should get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np

N_GROUPS = len(data)
HEIGHT = 1
rectangles = []

yticks = np.linspace(HEIGHT, N_GROUPS * HEIGHT * 2, N_GROUPS)
colors = ['g', 'r', 'b'] * (N_GROUPS // 3)

for (_, row), y, c in zip(data.iterrows(), yticks, colors):
    rec = {'xy': (row.start, y - HEIGHT/2),
           'width': row.end - row.start,
           'height': 1,
           'fill': False,
           'color': c
           }
    rectangles.append(rec)

for rec in rectangles:
    ax = plt.gca()
    p = Rectangle(**rec)
    ax.add_patch(p)

plt.yticks(yticks, data['group'])
plt.xlim([data['start'].min() - 1, data['end'].max() + 1])
plt.ylim([0, (N_GROUPS * HEIGHT * 2) + HEIGHT])
```

[image: plot]